# ASP.NET MVC code first many to many (bridge) table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, many-to-many

I started working with code first approach. It's kindda confusing... anyway I need to know how can I CRUD something using the bridged table. Let's for example say that I have 3 tables.(1 of which is the bridge table). Let's name them foo1 and foo2 while foo3 will be our bridge table. Now let's say I need to save a item from foo1 to foo2 (using the corresponding ID's in foo3). How do I do that? And basically the whole CRUD. Examples and resources would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide your sample code? Whatever you have done till now will be useful to determine your problem. I use code first with 2 approaches: 1) Fluent Entity Configuration 2) DataAnnotation so it will be helpful if you provide you sample code.

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota I use data annotations.. Anyway I need an article and some simple examples so I can get the hang of it

Comment: Ok. You should look into `http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx` link for complete details of many to many relationship. Happy coding :)

Comment: I hope this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application